# CSS - How can I change order of DIVs based on screen size?

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment

I have a CSS layout question.
I have 3 divs aligned next to each other horizontally. like this...

`div1` `div2` `div3`

I need the divs to change order as the screen gets smaller.  For example, at a certain size, they would appear like this. Div2 and 3 next to each other with div1 underneath.

`div2` `div3`

`div1`

And if you get even smaller, they would appear vertical in this order...

`div2`

`div1`

`div3`

I was able to achieve this by using `display:none` and creating duplicate versions of the divs and turning them on and off based on the screen size.  I hear that kind of thing is bad for SEO though.  Viewing my code, google would see multiple copies of the same data a few times.  Is there a better way to get this done?

---

Thank you for telling me about ORDER.  I'm getting close.  Now I need the DIV labeled TEXT to appear centered under the other 2 divs at 1200 width.  And then everything centered vertical at 800 width.

```css
#container {
display: flex;flex-flow: row wrap;justify-content: center;gap:50px 25px;
}

#div1 {width :150px;border:1px solid red;order:1;display:block}
#div2 {width :150px;border:1px solid red;order:2;display:block}
#div3 {width :150px;border:1px solid red;order:3;display:block}


@media (max-width: 1200px) {
#div1 {order:3;}
#div2 {order:1;}
#div3 {order:2;}
}


@media (max-width: 800px) {
#div1 {order:2;}
#div2 {order:1;}
#div3 {order:3;}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">


<div id="div1">
TEXT
</div>

<div id="div2">
Image
</div>

<div id="div3">
VIDEO
</div>



</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried useing `order`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Yes, use `order` at certain break points; very doable.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about Order.  I just edited my post.  I've got the divs changing order, but need them to wrap and center at the right width (see example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment suggested. You can use flexbox with [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property to achieve it. But you may also consider using grid layout for more percise control

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
}

.container .item {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px currentColor;
}

@media screen and (width < 1200px) {
  .container .item:nth-child(1) {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (width < 800px) {
  .container .item:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: initial;
  }
  
  .container .item:nth-child(3) {
    grid-row: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">TEXT</div>
  <div class="item">Image</div>
  <div class="item">Video</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a better way to achieve this responsive layout without duplicating content and using display: none. You can use CSS Flexbox or CSS Grid to create a responsive layout that reorders the divs based on the screen size.

Here's an example using CSS Flexbox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .item {
            flex: 1;
            min-width: 0; /* Allow items to shrink */
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            .item {
                flex-basis: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">div1</div>
        <div class="item">div2</div>
        <div class="item">div3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, the container uses display: flex to create a flex container, and flex-wrap: wrap allows the items to wrap to the next line when there isn't enough space. The media query (@media (max-width: 600px)) sets the flex-basis of the items to 100%, making them stack vertically on smaller screens.

You can adjust the media query breakpoint and styles according to your specific design requirements. This approach ensures a cleaner and more SEO-friendly code compared to duplicating content.